# Python / MongoDB - Problema con consulta incluyendo "OR" & "LIKE"

Tags: python, mongodb

Tengo el siguiente código que según **información de usuario** de un **formulario HTML** busca un registro en la base de datos MongoDB:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
Conector = MongoClient('localhost:27017')

Usuario_dato = REQUEST
dato = str(Usuario_dato['find'])

print dato

Datos = Conector['CRUD']
Tabla = Datos['usuarios']


Consulta = Tabla.find({
    "$or":[
        {
            "idUsuario": '/'+dato+'/' #también he intentado { "$regex": /dato/ >>> Falla, '/dato/' >>> también falla }
        },
        {
            "nombreUsuario":'/'+dato+'/'
        },
        {
            "emailUsuario":'/'+dato+'/'
        },
        {
            "telefonoUsuario":'/'+dato+'/'
        },
        {
            "edadUsuario":'/'+dato+'/'
        }
    ]
})

Recopilado = []

for e in Consulta:
    Pre_Recopilado = {}
    for x in e:
        Pre_Recopilado[str(x)] = str(e[x])
    Recopilado.append(Pre_Recopilado)
print json.dumps(Recopilado)
```

La **información de usuario** llega a **Usuario_data** por medio de *REQUEST*

A **dato** asigno el valor que me interesa del formulario enviado, en éste caso es *find* :

```
<input type="text" name="find">
```

En **Datos** y **Tabla** se enlaza la conexión a la base de datos *CRUD* y la tabla *usuarios*

**Consulta** contiene la consulta a realizarse, y és esto lo que falla.

En la base de datos tengo:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b9a5837a264d076dd40a12"),
    "idUsuario" : "1093796198",
    "nombreUsuario" : "Mart&iacute;n Berm&uacute;dez",
    "emailUsuario" : "alekxandermxtr@gmail.com",
    "telefonoUsuario" : "3002500989",
    "edadUsuario" : "19"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ba96d47a264d076dd43177"),
    "idUsuario" : "2135130062312",
    "nombreUsuario" : "Sofia Gonzales",
    "emailUsuario" : "sfg@gmail.com",
    "telefonoUsuario" : "3205623215",
    "edadUsuario" : "26"
}
```

La situación:

1. Busco en la base de datos ej: un número de documento de algún usuario que puede o no existir en los registros. Entonces digito sólo 1093 y envío la información.
2. Debo buscar ese **1093** en todos los campos o los campos que yo haya definido para su respectiva búsqueda, en éste caso **idUsuario**, **nombreUsuario**, **emailUsuario**, **telefonoUsuario** y finalmente **edadUsuario**.
3. Para realizar la consulta, debería haber un "**OR**" y posteriomente un "**LIKE**" para cada campo el cual indique que búsque los registros que *contengan*, *inicien*, o *terminen* en los caracteres dados, en éste caso: **1093**

Hasta donde tengo entendido para MongoDB una expresión regular *no* es un String. MongoDB toma los strings de forma literal, asi que no buscará en él si hay RegExp.

Entonces, Python desconoce el tipo de variable que intento buscar porque sería entonces */dato/*, eso para Python no es válido. Siendo *'/dato/'* (tener en cuenta las comillas) **sí** sería correcto, pero no lo es para MongoDB

La consulta falla, no encuentra nada.

¿Qué solución o alternativa hay para éste problema?

*(Y claro, sé que en MongoDB no existe OR como tal ni tampoco LIKE, busco una equivalencia que pueda llevarme a realizar lo mismo.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta:

Se debe importar re, de éste modo podrémos indicarle a Python que trate la variable como Expresión Regular.

```
import re. #Importar "libreria" de Expresiones Regulares
regex = re.compile(r'.*(%s).*'%dato) #Aqui se llama la funcion compile(), dentro de ella, se escribe r'' y dentro de las comillas puedes agregar variables como si se tratara de formato en **print**, por eso el %. 

# Éste RegEx es para buscar variables que contengan el valor, sea al principio, final, o en cualquier parte.

Consulta = Tabla.find({
    "$or":[
        {"idUsuario": regex}, #Aqui solo queda agregar la variable, ésta variable *no* es String, re.compile le ha indicado a Python que el contenido de la variable es Expresion Regular(regex)
        {"nombreUsuario": regex},
        {"emailUsuario": regex},
        {"telefonoUsuario": regex},
        {"edadUsuario": regex}
    ]
})
```

:)

Espero sea útil también para otros.